# Pass Multiple Select Values to a Javascript API function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableau-api

I will keep this simple.  First, these are snippets extracted from a larger document. So yes, I have the proper headers and source references, etc.

I have a `select` box.  I know how to call the function based on a single value selection.  I want to know how specifically to call this function `showOnly()` when the select box allows for `multiple` values.

The `select` box is

```
 <select id="select_a" name="color" multiple>
     <option selected="selected" class="options">Select desired detail</option>
     <option value="None" class="options" >None</option>        
     <option value="Investment Category" class="options">Investment Category</option>
     <option value="Company" class="options">Company</option>
     <option value="Budget Line" class="options">Budget Line</option>
     <option value="Market" class="options">Market</option>
     <option value="Organization" class="options">Organization</option>
     <option value="Segment" class="options">Segment</option>  
 </select>
```

So, how do I connect `multiple` values to the function `showOnly()` below.  With one value, `showOnly()` might look like this `showOnly('Segment','Cars')`. I know  `showOnly` with multiple values would like `showOnly('Segment,['Cars','Boats','Planes'])`.   Here is the function `showOnly()`

```
function showOnly(filterName, values) {
  sheet = mainViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
    sheet.applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
  } else {

    worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
    for(var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
        worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
      }
   }
};
```

Thoughts?? //Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var colOfSelectedOpt = document.getElementById("select_a").selectedOptions;

 var values = [];
 for(var i=0;i<colOfSelectedOpt.length;i++) {
         values.push(colOfSelectedOpt[i].value);
    }
```

`values` should give you array of selected items. You can pass this to function before calling or pass the id of select and get values inside function.

**Update**

```
function showOnly(filterName, idOfSelect) {

    var colOfSelectedOpt = document.getElementById(idOfSelect).selectedOptions;

    var values = [];
    for(var i=0;i<colOfSelectedOpt.length;i++) {
         values.push(colOfSelectedOpt[i].value);
    }      

 sheet = mainViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
     if(sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
         sheet.applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
      } else {

         worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
         for(var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
        worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
       }
  }
 };
```

Whenever you call `showOnly()` method pass the `id` of select dom for which you want this function to get called.

```
 <select id="select_a" name="color" onchange="showOnly('filterName', this.getAttribute('id'));" multiple>
```

Or If you want selection to work on some other button then fetch and `id` from associated select dropdown by id and pass it to function.

Comment: How on second option?

Comment: ...first, thanks for your help...  So, I am a noob.  I tried adding the element id `'#select_b'` (which replaced select_a) wherever you had `idOfSelect`.  It will not let me add it to the `function showOnly(filterName, idOfSelect)`  it wants a parameter or value defined there.   Adding to the definition of colOfSelectionOpt generates the following error `null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('#select_b').selectedOptions;`

Comment: @Hellyar does your html have `select` dropdown with `id` `select_b`?

Comment: It does now, but it was only a minor edit so it would not contradict with my actual test page.

Comment: Note the original `function showOnly(filterName, values)`

Comment: @Hellyar dont replace `idOfSelect` everywhere in code. Just the place where you call it. That is in HTML select dropwdown `onchange` for select element. (in updated code)

Comment: Also, should I add the id `select_b` to the html where you have `this.getAttribute('id')` ?

Comment: Yes; you could have this for select_b as `onchange="showOnly('filterName', 'select_b');"` or Just add this `onchange="showOnly('filterName', this.getAttribute('id'));"`  to any select dropdown for which you need this function to be called.

Comment: @Hellyar Also for `filterName` you need to pass the value of `container` for that workshet.  Refer this. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_filtering.htm

Comment: Got it.  I had to leave the quotes off the ID when adding it to `function showOnly(filterName, 'idOfSelect')`  I also had to hardwire the filterName to segment since I don't have a value for it or ask the function to find it.  But, it now works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since `HTMLOptionsCollection`'s are array-like objects, I'm not familiar with any way to use Array.prototype.map() to create a new array of selected values. But we can alway use the good old fashioned for loop. Here's an ES6 approach:

```
const select = document.getElementById('select_a');
const on_change = (event) => {
  const options = event.target.options;
  let values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
          values.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }

  console.log('Pass these values to your function:', values);
};

select.addEventListener('change', on_change);
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/yemoxizaso/1/edit?js,console,output

And if you can't use ES6, here's an ES5 approach:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select_a');
var on_change = function(event) {
  var options = event.target.options;
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
          values.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }

  console.log('Pass these values to your function:', values);
};

select.addEventListener('change', on_change);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an object built-in `Function` as a property called `arguments` which is a local variable that can pass in an unlimited amount of values. `arguments` is array-like in that it will index every value it's given and it has a couple of methods including length. I have no idea if my example works since half of those functions and variables are not provided. `collArgs()` should be able to take a number of parameters and return the values in an indexed array-like fashion. From there, I've assigned `values` to store the values of `arguments` and now it can be passed into your functions.

Please read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for a better explanation and working examples 
    args = new arguments()

```js
function collArgs() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
   arguments[i];
  }
  return arguments;
}

var values = collArgs();

function showOnly(filterName, values) {
  var sheet = mainViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
    sheet.applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
  } else {

    var worksheetArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
    for(var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
        worksheetArray[i].applyFilterAsync(filterName, values, 'REPLACE');
      }
   }
};
```